# Laravel 5.2 Custom Post Data Not Passing

Tags: ajax, laravel-5

I'm having difficulty passing a custom build data object to the Laravel controller using ajax.  This is very frustrating as I've had good luck using AJAX to build a fairly robust web application thus far.  However, this one is proving difficult.

I'm building surveys where questions can have more than one answer (select all that apply) and so rather than just use the form.serialize() function I wrote my own to build a response object I could iterate through and save records on the server side.  The function is below

```
function TraceHrForm(e)
{
  e.preventDefault();
  var post_url=$(this).attr('url');
  var get_url=$(this).data('url');
  var tag=$(this).attr('tag');
  var checked = $("input[name*='sq']:checked");
  var addinfo=$("input[name='additional_info']");
  post_data=[];
  checked.each(function(){
    post_data.push({'sq_id': this.id, 'response': this.value});
  });
  addinfo.each(function(){
    if(this.value.length>0)
    {
      post_data.push({'sq_id':this.id,'additional_info':this.value});
    }
  });
  pdata={survey_response: post_data};
  $.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url: post_url,
    data: pdata,
    headers: {'Content-type': "application/json"}
    }).done(function(response){
      console.log(response);
    });
}
```

I can see in Chrome Dev tools that the object `pdata` is built correctly and the routes.php file sends the request to the right controller function but when I examine the request object in the controller function, there is no data present.

```
public function submit(Request $request, TraceHrSurvey $thr)
    {
      return var_dump($request->all());
```

I've also tried just looking at the `$request` object as well as `$request->input(survey_response)`

Any thoughts would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Ahmed but I was only interested in passing the JSON data to the server.  I did manage to solve my problem by modifying my code in the following way.

```
function TraceHrForm(e)
{
  e.preventDefault();
  var post_url=$(this).attr('url');
  var get_url=$(this).data('url');
  var tag=$(this).attr('tag');
  var checked = $("input[name*='sq']:checked");
  var addinfo=$("input[name='additional_info']");
  var post_data='{"survey_response": ['; <--Modified from array to object
  checked.each(function(){
    post_data += '{"sq_id":"' + this.id + '", "response": "' + this.value + '"},';
  });
  addinfo.each(function(){
    if(this.value.length>0)
    {
      post_data += '{"sq_id":"' + this.id + '", "additional_info": "' + this.value + '"},';
    }
  });
  var ind = post_data.length -1;
  post_data = post_data.substring(0,ind);
  post_data += ']}';
  $.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url: post_url,
    data: post_data
  }).done(function(response){
    if(response=="1")
    {
      loadComponent(post_url,"#trace_hr");
    }
    else {
      alert('Trace Survey Did not save');
    }
  });
}
```

The in my Laravel controller function I simply made the call

```
public function submit(Request $request, $id)
    {
     $jdata=$request->json('survey_response');
```

and I had an array of associative arrays I could iterate over.  I'm not sure how that worked but it did so I'm happy.

Answer (score 0):

try to return a json response back to the page like

```
$sentdata = $request->all();
return $response()->json([
    'result' => 'success',
    'data'   => $sentdata,
]);
```

and then u can cosole.log ur sent data inside ur page to check the process, using dot notation like

```
console.log(response.result);
```